# Exception "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Ljava/util/Iterator" After adding JDK11 dependencies

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-11

We are facing this issue after upgrading from JDK10 to JDK11. The only thing we changed is, we have added below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Not understanding Why it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

I had this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version> </dependency>
```

Removing that fixed the same exception. 
Maybe you've got the same dependency in your tree?

Answer (score 0):

Try this dependency if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Shall I remove the above dependency and add yours ?

Comment: You can keep them both and try.

Comment: Nope, It didn't help